# How to echo "test text" | myscript.sh and echo from the script back out

Tags: bash

As in the title, I want to

```
$ echo "test text" | myscript.sh
```

and then get:

```
test text
```

out from myscript.sh

I'm going to do other things of course. This is just the concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious answer is to use cat.  By default it will read from stdin and echo to stdout.

```
#!/bin/sh

cat
```